# Running jhipster-registry in native profile: central-config folder not rode

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config

I am currently trying to run jhipster-registry  in dev profile to serve the configurations to a jhipster microservice application.

I've followed this [official jhipster registry doc](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry/) and:

have built it from sources, and launched it as follow:

```
./jhipster-registry-3.0.0.war --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

And as the doc states, i have put the `central-config` directory containing `<mymicrosericeappname>-dev.yml` alongside the jhipster-registry generated war file.

When i launch jhipster-registry, everything is ok,
but when i run my microservice application, it connects to the registry (i can see it in the jhipster-registry dashboard), but i realize that it is reading the application-dev.yml file located at src/main/resources/config/ inside the microservice app.

I dont know if i misplaced the central-config folder...
That said, i really need to know what's wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested the config endpoints using a browser to see if the registry responds correctly?

Comment: no, and to be honest i don't really know what i have to do. Do you ask me to test config rest APIs with a browser? For that i have to locate them first.

Comment: Exactly or using curl command. Please read https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_quick_start  if your app is named "foo" and your registry runs locally on default port `http://localhost:8761/config/foo/dev` should return its application properties for profile dev

Comment: the registry responds correctly, but points that the property resource file is https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config/application.yml , that said, it means that the central-config directory is not rode... i think that i misplaced it, where do i have to put it to get it rode by the registry at dev mode startup ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GaelMarziou, his answer helped me found why the `central-config` was not being rode.
In fact the Spring Cloud Config bootstrap configuration for the "dev" profile `bootstrap.yml` file gives this:

```
cloud:
        config:
            server:
                git:
                    uri: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry-sample-config
                native:
                    search-locations: file:./central-config
```

So each time i ran jhipster-registry, it was pointing the git repo and not the `central-config` directory. 
To get it work, i had to launch the registry in dev,native profile :

```
./jhipster-registry-3.0.0.war --spring.profiles.active=dev,native
```

Nevertheless  the [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/jhipster-registry/#installation) states this:

> Using the dev profile will run the JHipster Registry with the dev and the native profiles.

Which is not really true... considering my struggling.

Answer (score 2):

The config directory is specified in `bootstrap.yml` in `search-locations` property.

```
spring:
    cloud:
        config:
            server:
                native:
                    search-locations: file:./central-config
```

Rather than specifying a relative path (relative to where you launched the regsitry from), you may want to specify an absolute path:

```
                    search-locations: file:/home/something/central-config
```

Also rather than using `dev` profile, you can use prod with native :

```
./jhipster-registry-3.0.0.war --spring.profiles.active=prod,native
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer did really helped me, in fact when running in dev profile, as the bootstrap.yml specifies git server property, the git location is rode , to get the native search-locations rode, i had to run jhipster-registry in dev,native profile. So the jhipster-registry doc is a little bit confusing about that.

Comment: Feel free to report an issue on doc in github and propose a pull request